# Area bounded by the graphs $y = x^2 – 2x – 6$ and $y = 6 – x^2$?

Tags: calculus

Find the area bounded by the graphs of the following functions 
$$y = x^2 – 2x – 6$$ and $$y = 6 – x^2$$

Are the points $-3$ and $2$? Where to go form there?

Comment: ∫((6 – x^2 )-(x^2  – 2x – 6))dx = ?

Answer (score 1):

The points of intersection can be found by solving

$$x^2-2x-6=6-x^2 \Longleftrightarrow x^2-x-6=0 \Longleftrightarrow (x-3)(x+2)=0$$

Thus $x=\color{red}-2$ and $x=\color{red}+3$ are the points of intersection.

In the interval $[-2,3]$, $6-x^2>x^2-2x-6$, therefore the area of the bounded region is

$$\int_{-2}^36-x^2-(x^2-2x-6)\,dx$$

> $$=\displaystyle \int_{-2}^3 -2x^2+2x+12 \,dx$$
> $$=\displaystyle \left. \left(-\frac{2}{3}x^3+x^2+12x\right)\right|_{-2}^3$$
> $$=\boxed{41\frac{2}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the two points where the two curves meet - ie x such that y1 = y2.
Then integrate the difference between the two functions over that range.

Answer (score 0):

all that you need to do for this one is break it into 2 integrals and add them together: $\int_{-2}^{2}(6-x^2)-(x^2-2x-6)dx +\int_{-3}^{-2} (x^2-2x-6) -(6 - x^2) dx$

(I chose -2 as the point of division because that is where the curves intersect)